# Maven and JavaDoc: install additional (generated) files

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

My project can generate some additional help files automatically from the source code.

How do I have maven install these files into the generated JavaDoc package?

I couldn't fingure out how to have Maven:

1. run some class to generate the additional documentation, e.g. compile and launch `src/main/java/mypackage/ListOptions.java` aka `mypackage.ListOptions` to produce a list of all available options/modules/examples/etc. .
2. install the output files (I only could get Maven to install files from `src/main/javadoc/resources` into the `site/apidocs/resources` subfolder; but I want this documentation to live in the top level `site/apidocs` folder; more precisely I don't care about the `site` part at all, but about having a complete documetation in `mypackage-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar`; including non-Javadoc-generated auxillary information linked from javadoc).

Minimal example - Plugin configuration for maven:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <docfilessubdirs>true</docfilessubdirs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Directory layout:

```
./pom.xml
./src/main/java/foobar/GenerateNonstatic.java
./src/main/javadoc/staticfile.js
./src/main/javadoc/resources/insubfolder.png
```

`mvn package` produces: javadoc in `./target/apidocs` and `./target/foobar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar`. The file `target/apidocs/resources/insubfolder.png` ends up in folder `target/apidocs/resources` (and the `.jar`), but the `staticfile.js` is not installed.

How to run `GenerateNonstatic.java` to have the output included in the javadoc `.jar` is unclear to me. I don't see a hook to have exec:exec it run *after* javadoc, and *before* `./target/foobar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar` is built...

Comment: Please show your pom.xml file and directory structure showing where  the doc generation class is and the desired output location.

Comment: The doc generation class is in the Java source, `src/main/java` (which you won't see in the `pom.xml` yet, because it's unclear to me how to configure an `exec` task so it ends up in the javadoc...) and the desired output location is *whatever* the `package` and `javadoc` magic uses to build the `...-javadoc.jar` package.

Comment: @333kenshin I've added a minimal example, but I don't see how this would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story, short answer. Both the `javadoc:javadoc` and `javadoc:jar` mojos have their drawbacks. The first is meant to build the javadoc for reporting; the latter will build the javadoc (into a different directory) and produce a jar package.

Some of the suggested answers did not work well because of this - they would execute javadoc twice.

But I noticed that **javadoc does not care if the folder already exists or contains files**.

So my solution is simple: generate the desired additional files in `prepare-package`, and the regular `javadoc:jar` task adds the regular javadoc and pacakges it nicely.

This will work **as long as you don't intend to *modify* files generated by javadoc** (which I, fortunately, don't - I only add additional documentation.

The resulting `pom.xml` is like this:

```
<plugins>
    <!-- copy additional javadoc resources -->
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/apidocs</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/javadoc</directory>
                <excludes>
                <!-- overview.html is integrated by javadoc -->
                <exclude>${basedir}/src/main/javadoc/overview.html</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <!-- Generate additional files for javadoc -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-extra-javadoc</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                       <!-- java is okay, but you only can have one -->
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>...</configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <!-- Build JavaDoc -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: I now use Gradle. Maven just is too annoying once it gets complex.

Answer (score 2):

Eric,

If you are uncomfortable modifying the javadoc executable, another option is to break apart your javadoc call into 2 separate steps (javadoc and jar) and make your call between them by manipulating the Maven build lifecycle via `<phase>` tag:

- phase: generate-sources => maven-javadoc-plugin:javadoc
- phase: compile          => exec-maven-plugin:java
- phase: package          => maven-javadoc-plugin:jar

**note**: use exec:java, not exec:exec to run java classes

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-javadocs</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>javadoc</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-nonstatic-javadocs</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>foobar.GenerateNonstatic</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
       </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Note: `exec:java` apparently does not support multiple executions. Since I have two generators run, I needed to use `exec:exec`.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Doesn't entirely work yet. It seems that the first goal will run javadoc, into the reporting folder. The second will run javadoc *again*, into the `target/apidocs` folder. I "hacked" this by having setting the reporting directory for the first run, and using `/bin/true` as "javadoc executable" for the second. This causes a warning, but building works. But I've settled for a much simpler solution now.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: Run a commandline command with the Exec-Maven-Plugin or use the Maven-Ant-Plugin and embed custom tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Eric,

Your example is indeed helpful. Please do try to always include concrete examples as much as possible when asking the question.

The simplest approach would be to write your own [Alternate Javadoc tool](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/alternate-javadoc-tool.html) and pass that into Maven via the `<javadocExecutable>` tag. This example comes from the link above:

```
<project>
  ...
  <reporting> (or <build>)
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <javadocExecutable>C:\jdk1.6.0\bin\javadoc.exe</javadocExecutable>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </reporting> (or </build>)
  ...
</project>
```

Hope that helps.